# How to automatically check if no changes were introduced since the last stash and drop them?

Tags: git, git-stash

The use-case scenario is as follows:

```
git checkout branch-1
[introduce some changes I don't want to commit (but want to preserve)]
git stash save "my useful changes"

git checkout branch-2
[do some business with branch-2]

git checkout branch-1
git stash apply # the last stash which is "my useful changes"
```

Now, say I want to go back to `branch-2` again. I am almost sure didn't introduce any new changes, so I don't want to create another stash if the changes are the same. *I want to still have my stash with the same stash message.*

I can manually check if the changes are the same (compare the diffs). And then either `git reset / git stash; git stash drop` in case they are indeed the same or create a new stash if they are not.

Is there a way to to this more automatically?

Solutions which are not good enough:

- If I simply do `git stash` again, it creates a new stash (even if the contents and the message are identical to those of the top stash).
- If I use `git stash pop` each time after I return to `branch-1`, I'll loose the stash message and so I'll have to re-type it each time.
- If I do hard reset, I have to first check to make sure I didn't introduce any new changes other that changes in my top stash (so it's not automatic).

You could always say "write a script and it'll be automatic" and it's true. I want to know is there a feature integrated in git. So I consider a simple well-founded "No" a good answer.

Comment: Maybe I'm not following your scenario properly, but I'd rather just create a branch and commit my changes to that branch, instead of stashing them. Then there's nothing to worry about (did I stash w/the right name, did I pop my changes). Given that you can create as many stashes or branches as you want, I see little benefit in using a stash when you think you might want to pop/push things from the stash multiple times.

Comment: @SunilD., good point. I think, I'll go with creating new branches. The only downside is the additional branch (could be a little confusing if you have many branches).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [git index](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository) for that.

Taking from where you left off:

```
$ git checkout branch-1
$ git stash apply # the last stash which is "my useful changes"
$ git add -A
# ... work on branch-1
$ git status
```

If there are any changes to the state you started with you will see some files as partially unstaged:

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   <file>
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   <file>
#
```

If this is the case, then you need to update the stash. Otherwise, you can simply do a hard reset and continue with the existing stash.

Alternatively, you can add the changes to index *before* saving them to stash (with `git stash -k`) and apply the stash with `git stash apply --index` — this saves you one command after switching a branch.